# Too many open files in system in kubernetes cluster

Tags: linux, kubernetes, etcd

While running a Kubernetes clusters, I keep hitting the following error after a while, it seems there is a bug about etcd, has anyone counter the same issue and has a workaround?

> FailedSync    Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for
>   "POD" with RunContainerError: "runContainer: API error (500): Cannot
>   start container
>   f0a2b72747555228a89592ae28436f521ba389623f53ef5f2103f4aea3f7ac4e: [8]
>   System error: too many open files in system\n"

Is this only me or has any counter similar issues?

Comment: Not a programming question, voted to close. Maybe try serverfault?

Comment: @tink i see, thanks! will close